Obsolete attribute - Avoid magic string
I want to mark an old class as Obsolete and redirect to the new class in the Obsolete attribute comment. However, if I write the new class name as a magic string, I won't be able to use the might of IDE.
For example, if I rename my class, I will loose the "link". And the reader won't be able to Ctrl + click on my comment to go to the new class.
The official documentation does seems to say that it is not possible, but I find strange that nobody has this need.
Instead of
// Mark OldProperty As Obsolete.
[ObsoleteAttribute("This property is obsolete. Use NewProperty instead.", false)]
public static string OldProperty
{ get { return "The old property value."; } }

public static string NewProperty
{ get { return "The new property value."; } }

I would like to be able to write
[ObsoleteAttribute($"This property is obsolete. Use {nameof(NewProperty)} instead.", false)]

As a workaround, I can use the XML doc, but it's not the best way to do it.
/// <remarks>Replaced by <see cref="LoadBrainIndMeasMessTable"/></remarks>


"I would like to be able to write ..." -- as of C# 10 (.NET 6), you can. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ6QNoDywAzhADYwAuMACgAkAIgAqACwCW7UgAcoEOTCi8AnqRmkIHbnxgA6UgFV2MWgDsAhgFsYEAGYCAcjADuABUXLVagJQAvpoW7PxWACYGIgA0pA5WXGZ+ALr0jCTkOEiZAAykLFzhXkoq6mkMNKQA5ny05ADspOIS5tzh8t6lGgBuCQCuhiIA3KRBAYTl5GQYWbmkrp6dvpOVNbx1GI3N5hbuHSW+pL1cA1EjY4QBQA=

Before C#10, you can write "This property is obsolete. Use " + nameof(NewProperty) + " instead."

Thanks! I forgot I was on an old project. I got An attribute argument must be a constant expression, 'typeof()' expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type when trying to do so, I did not think to check in later language version. Would you like to write it as an answer so I can accept it as resolved?

As an aside, classes that define attributes by convention always end with "Attribute", but when you use them as attributes, you drop that part of the name: [Obsolete] not [ObsoleteAttribute]

This is already supported in C# 10 (.NET 6):
public class C
{
    [Obsolete($"This property is obsolete. Use {nameof(NewProperty)} instead")]
    public static string OldProperty => "The old property value.";

    public static string NewProperty => "The new property value.";
}

Before then, string concatenation should work for any C# version:
public class C
{
    [Obsolete("This property is obsolete. Use " + nameof(NewProperty) + " instead")]
    public static string OldProperty => "The old property value.";

    public static string NewProperty => "The new property value.";
}

